# SintaxError:invalid o unexpeted toked

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

It's my first time doing this and I get these **errors**:

```
SintaxError:invalid o unexpeted toked
```

could you help me with this?

```
console.log('bot in orders');
var Discord = require(‘discord.js’);
var bot = new Discord.Client();

bot.on('menssage', (menssage) => {
    if (message.contenet == 'hi') {
        message.channel.sendMessage('Hi! :D');
    }
});
bot.login('TOKEN');
```

Comment: can you please provide more details ? 
The full stask off errors ?

Comment: fixed some words

Answer (score 1):

`require(‘discord.js’)`

Your quote signs are wrong, they should be `''` -- `require('discord.js')`

It breaks the rest of the code.